# How to resolve E0658 (underscore naming) in Rust's Cargo Check?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am getting an error running `cargo check` with the `rust-s3` crate.
All of the documentation I have found seems to indicate this is a settled issue.

Am I missing a setting or an option or something in Cargo.toml?

This is the check error:

```
error[E0658]: naming constants with `_` is unstable
   --> /Users/andrevan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bytes-0.5.4/src/bytes.rs:911:1
    |
911 | const _: [(); 0 - mem::align_of::<Shared>() % 2] = []; // Assert that the alignment of `Shared` is divisible by 2.
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: for more information, see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54912
```

Comment: What version of `rustc` are you using? (`rustc --version`).

Comment: Hum, I thought I was using 1.42.0, but when I do `rustc --version`, I get 1.36.0.

Comment: I think I found the problem.  I was using a `brew` installed version of rust that was `1.36.0` while `rustup` was using the `1.42.0` version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Courtesy of @SCappella's comment, I found that I using a `brew` installed version of Rust that was older than the underscore fix.

I `brew remove rust` and then reinstalled the Rust toolchain and it works now.

Thanks @SCappella.